# Python: Adding self to a signature, Pycharm not displaying correct tool tip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Using python 3.6

I'm have difficulty getting Pycharm to display the correct signature.

I Have a helper decorator `add_signature` that adds the signature of an object
to the function it's being applied to.

It seems to work, when I take a look at the `__signature__` attribute but PyCharm does't display the correct tool tip.

Am I doing it wrong? Or can someone else verify my findings?

Example:

```
from inspect import Signature, Parameter, signature
from functools import wraps

def add_signature(class_obj):
    """Add the signature of an object to the function"""

    def wrapper(func):

        sig = Signature((Parameter(name='self', kind=1), *tuple(signature(class_obj).parameters.values())))
        @wraps(func)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        wrap.__signature__ = sig
        return wrap

    return wrapper

class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self, fizz, buzz, bat, bar):
        self.fizz = fizz; self.buzz = buzz, self.bat = bat; self.bar = bar


class Foo(object):

    @add_signature(Bar)
    def create_bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Bar(*args, **kwargs)
```

[image]

---

Ok, I discovered that using it as a static method works.

Too bad if it needed `self`

from functools import wraps
    from inspect import signature

```
def add_signature(class_obj):
    """Add the signature of an object to the function"""

    def wrapper(func):
        sig = signature(class_obj)

        @wraps(func)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        wrap.__signature__ = sig
        return wrap

    return wrapper


class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, fizz, buzz, bat, bar):
        self.fizz = fizz
        self.buzz = buzz
        self.bat = bat
        self.bar = bar


class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    @add_signature(Bar)
    def create_bar(*args, **kwargs):
        return Bar(*args, **kwargs)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So using `inspect.signature` on an object will remove the self parameter.

Using `inspect.signature` on an objects `__init__` does not remove the 'self' parameter.

This works:

```
from inspect import signature
from functools import wraps

def add_signature(class_obj):
    """Add the signature of an object to the function"""

    def wrapper(func):


        sig = signature(class_obj)
        @wraps(func)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        wrap.__signature__ = sig
        return wrap

    return wrapper

class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self, fizz, buzz, bat, bar):
        self.fizz = fizz; self.buzz = buzz; self.bat = bat; self.bar = bar


class Foo(object):

    @add_signature(Bar.__init__)
    def create_bar(*args, **kwargs):
        return Bar(*args, **kwargs)
```

[image]